# a multidimensional arrays in Ruby is filling all indexes with duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

in Ruby 2.6.6, I wanted to pre-create an array of arrays, and insert some values into one index. What I notice is the array puts all values into all arrays when doing like this:

```
  matrix = Array.new( 3, [] )
  5.times do |n| matrix[0] << n end
  p matrix 

  # outputs: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

What I was hoping to get to:

```
  [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [], []]
```

How should I do this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with your array instantiation.

It should be

```
matrix = Array.new(3){Array.new}
```

From the [2.6.6](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.6/Array.html) documentation:

> `Array.new(3, true) #=> [true, true, true]`
>
> Note that the second argument populates the array with references to
> the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you
> need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as
> Symbols, numbers, true or false.
>
> To create an array with separate objects a block can be passed
> instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as
> hashes, strings or other arrays:
>
> `Array.new(4) {Hash.new}    #=> [{}, {}, {}, {}]`